# Could the Earth-2149 Squirrel Girl destroy Colonel America's shield?

Tags: marvel, captain-america, vibranium, squirrel-girl

On Earth-2149 - the Zombie universe - [Colonel America](http://marvel.wikia.com/Steven_Rogers_(Earth-2149))'s shield is made of a Vibranium-Steel alloy instead of pure Vibranium. Also, in that universe, [Squirrel Girl](http://marvel.wikia.com/Doreen_Green_(Earth-616))'s squirrels are as undead as everything else. This means that they feel no pain, and will not stop gnawing/clawing at something even after their teeth/claws physically rip out or break off.

So... **could Zombie Squirrel Girl make her zombie squirrels damage Colonel America's shield?**

[image]

Comment: Just because you won't stop doesn't mean you'll succeed.  I can punch a tank until my arm falls off, but it won't destroy the tank.

Comment: Then again, it's Squirrel Girl, so obviously the answer is yes.

Comment: Two downvotes. Some people have no appreciation for a good, albeit silly, question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short Answer: No**

In the Mohs scale of mineral hardness, teeth have a [hardness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohs_scale_of_mineral_hardness) of 5, where as steel has a hardness between 4 to 4.5. So the teeth are slightly harder.

If the shield were made only of steel, the zombie squirrels could scratch it. Given enough scratches (like, a bajillion), they should be able to eventually bore a hole through it.

I think it is fair to assume that vibranium is at least as hard as titanium. With a hardness of 6, titanium is safe from zombie squirrels.

Since his shield has the ultra resilient vibranium in it; it is unlikely the zombie squirrels can scratch it. Their teeth, bones, and everything else would wear away long before the shield showed even a scratch.

On the other hand. You have to consider that Squirrel Girl took out Thanos.

[image]

And Thanos shattered Captain America's shield.

[image]

So what we have here is a classic paper/rock/scissors scenario.

> Squirrel Girl beats Thanos, Thanos beats Captain America's shield, Captain America beats Squirrel Girl.

Comment: Where do Lizard and Spock fit in? '-)

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to go with absolutely no. It's been established that Captain America's shield is in fact made of an alloy of Steel and Vibranium in *other* universes as well, including the main continuity universe where is has been proven to be utterly impenetrable to all but the most alpha of mutant/godly powers.

Although Squirrel Girl's little evil buddies may have near-infinite patience, it's unlikely they can make a dent in a shield that has utterly shrugged off (without a scratch) impacts from Mjolnir, punches from the Hulk and about a gazillion bullet-strikes.

[image]

Comment: What made the vibranium bond to the steel?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - Dunno. Probably worthy of its own question.

Comment: Better yet... how do they attach the handle and/or straps to the inside of the shield? You can't exactly use screws or rivets...

Comment: @Omegacron - I see no good reason they couldn't use glue, suction or powerful magnets. You might as well ask how they make Teflon stick to non-stick pans when it should all just fall out.

Comment: Teflon... pans... time for a new question on the chemistry SE.

Answer (score -1):

Well pure Vibranium can pierce the diamond skin of Emma Frost. Since the shield is a vibranium alloy, it'll shatter Squirrel Girl's teeth.

[image: vibranium blade piercing Emma Frost's diamond throat]